# Getting null value when i submit the formControl value?

Tags: angularjs, angular, multidimensional-array, formarray

I have created a form group with an empty array. Then I created a dropdown list where the user can select a value.

If the selected value matches with one in my list then it should append the corresponding array values into a new form group field.

### Example:

CustomerType Dropdown with possible selections: **Salaried**, **self employeed**

If the salaried option is selected then the sub array contains Documents list like adhar card, pan card, voter id etc..

```
array['Salaried'] => ['adhar card', 'pan card', 'voter']
```

When it is selected then I need to set these values to new form group field like docs:[].

sample code: 
`this.tableForm.controls.classDetails.value[position].docs = this.docsArray;`

output:**customerType: "Salaried"
docs: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]**
 while using this I am able to get the result, but when I submit it, it is changed to null. output like : **customerType: "Salaried"
docs: null**

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Please share the code for form group, where your are appending the values to an array on page load i,e ngOnInit() function. For Example:: 

this.abcForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      rowData: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
JSON.stringify([{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]);
```

then set value this string